# Why Auto_Increment not working in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

When I run this code, it is not run successfully.

Comment: Can you also post the error message that you get? Also, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I ran this code successfully in mysql database. Which database you are using?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Answer (score 4):

### Syntax for MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

### Syntax for SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int
);
```

### Syntax for Oracle

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Microsoft SQL Server then change to IDENTITY instead of Auto_Number. If it's Postgres then I believe you want SERIAL as the datatype instead of INT. If this is MySQL then it should work as-is.

What RDBMS are you using?